# No module named 'gspread'

Tags: python-3.x, erpnext, frappe

**Below file runs successfully when run direct on the console, but give an error: No module named 'gspread' on server**

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint

class GoogleSheet():

    scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    #creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
    creds = gspread.service_account()
    #client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    sh = creds.open("DI ITEM SHEET")  # Open the spreadhseet
    wks = sh.worksheet("2022-APR") # Open the workhseet

    data = wks.get_all_records()
```

Comment: `gspread` is an external Python library. Make sure you have added it in your `requirements.txt` file for your custom app, and then run `bench update` on your server so that the library is installed.

Comment: After adding it into the "requirements.txt", try ```bench setup requirements```